# CommitProperties in a custom component doesn't work with percent width

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component, measurement

My problem is pretty much described in the title. Just a few details .. I'm creating a custom component (based on ComboBox) and overriding some base methods. Recently I've found it acts weird when I set it's width in percents, rather than a fixed width. It tends to continuously call the `commitProperties` method and fail in the end. When I set it's width to fixed value - all works like a charm. What am I missing to implement? Here's some code ..

```
override protected function commitProperties():void {
        super.commitProperties();

        //some stuff ...

        TextInput(textInput).setSelection(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
        if (cursorPosition == textInput.text.length || cursorPosition == 0) {
            TextInput(textInput).horizontalScrollPosition = (cursorPosition == 0) ? 0 : textInput.width;
        }
    }
```

Here, the `textInput.width` properly returning a calculated value, in both cases.
And, just for a case, if it's needed:

```
override protected function measure():void {
        super.measure();
        measuredWidth = 160;
    }
```

I'm not sure if something else is needed .. just ask if so.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not obvious but it is generally a good practise to call `super.commitProperties();` at the end of overridden `commitProperties()` implementation rather than at the beginning.

If your `//some stuff...` block invalidates properties it won't be handled correctly if you called `super.commitProperties();` on the first line.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for advice. But unfortunately, it not solving my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to debug this kind of issue without a full code...

If you are extending Flex 3 MX ComboBox have a look at `ComboBase.updateDisplayList()` to understand when / how textInput is sized.

The `textInput.width` is updated in `ComboBase.updateDisplayList()` so you shouldn't rely on this value during `commitProperties()`. You can try moving your scroll position logic to the end of `updateDisplayList()` of your component (at this point width should be updated).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks .. after applying tons of variants, I've got it working. The problem was at  N'th nesting level .. so, this was a reason for me to miss that :) Thanks for your time.